# Holding HD Platters above a fire - is it safe?

Tags: toxicity

I already did this for a short <= 30s durations about 6 times to my old HD platters (the mirror-like CD/DVD disk) + immediatelly pouring cold water over it. After the fact I realized that it may not have been the healthy choice...

Are HD platters toxic to have over fire? I didn't see any smoke (saw steam when pouring water) but I just want to make sure.

Comment: Someone has to ask so I will. Why would you do this?

Comment: To try to destroy the data it holds.

Comment: Just snap them in two.